# React Native - What is the difference between those two apps in which one is using the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` and another don't?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I recently moved to `react native` and created a small application and it works just fine, so, i further start exploring the `react native`.

I found the `AppRegistry` api and i don't use this api in my existing app but my app is working fine then why to use the `AppRegistry.registerComponent`.

What is the purpose of using it if apps works just fine without using it. What is the difference between those two apps in which one is using the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` and another don't. A little real world example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

**Edited:**

I did a bit of research on it and found that everyone is saying it is used to `register a component` and that's it, what kind of registration it is, what is meant by `register a component`, what it is all about?

Comment: Have you been using Expo for making react native projects ?

Comment: i am using the native development method, not expo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppRegistry specifies delegates the actual communication between the JS and native by letting the native application know about the JS entry point and many other information about the application resources that the bundle should know. It exposes various methods that helps in the delegation like spawning of a **background service** in android using the `registerHeadlessTask` and `startHeadlessTask()`.

Comment: **Comment Part #1**:
Let say i have component **AppLogin** and it is shown when the user is logging in to his account, and i register this component with the **AppRegistry.registerComponent()**, and have another component that is **AppMain** which is loaded always when the user successfully logged in to his account and will be always loaded when next time user will open the app because the user is already in active session of login.

Comment: **Comment Part #2**:
So, when the app will be next time loaded on active session the **AppRegistry.registerComponent()** will contain the **AppLogin** but not **AppMain** but the user is logged in and **AppMain** is loaded, so, whether the **AppRegistry.registerComponent()** will target the **AppMain** or it will still targeting **AppLogin** which we don't need because the user is now logged in. What will be the scenario in that case?

Comment: @DhuBytes This does not goes like registering each of your UI components separately with the AppRegistry. You only register **Your Application root component** i.e. the root of your application in which the whole application will live. and then you make your application hierarchy using navigation. So with your use case there should be a root component say App, that will render a navigation stack containing your login and your AppMain. So your App is to be registered with the AppRegistry.

Comment: So you mean the name which we initiate when doing the *react-native init something*, so, in that case the *something* is my root component? Can you please do a little example so i will accept your answer !!!

Comment: If you go to `index.js` in your project root then you will get to see that by default there is an import from  `App.js` which is actual root component of you application that is being registered to the AppRegistry.

Comment: So it means that we don't have to use `AppRegistry.registerComponent()` in `App.js` because the exported component from the `App.js` is already registered in the `index.js`, i just check the index file,is i am correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. :)

Comment: Can you tell one more thing where to get the detailed information about this api. It looks incomplete here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry. Do you have any resource to share that contains the complete reference to learn this api?

Comment: You might not want to study about this anymore in the beginning of your React Native journey as this is most rarely used one. You will only use this when you will be quite comfortable in developing complex applications or when you would want to register any service that directly interacts with Native code. 
And also, React Native documentation is the only documentation that i found so far other are more vague.

Answer (score 2):

`AppRegistry.registerComponent` is used to register your root component of the app. Its just like void main in java class. If you are using an expo project you will not see this line because expo does everything by itself without letting us see how actually things work in native environments. Everything that you write in app.js will be taken as entry point of your app.

Comment: I am not using expo, i am using the native development method

Comment: What if i don't use it?

Comment: This Api only works in projects created with `react-native init`. Have you created it with Create React Native App.?

Comment: Create React Native App makes it easy to start working on React Native apps by removing native code build tools from the equation.

Comment: my question is different from the comment you added before **this comment** dear. This is not the thing i am looking for. Anyways thanks i got the answer !!!

Comment: If so, then you will always have to register your root component then include your app's screen in navigation in that root component.